# Eclipse keep changing Build Path configuration for a Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm configuring a specific Build Path for a project and Eclipse keep reverting my changes after each build with Maven (though the build is working fine).

I'm changing

- default output target folder for classes of the project
- adding a folder for external classes

I use integrated Maven plugin in Eclipse, why is it (or Eclipse) reverting my changes after each build?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :**

Adding the following to maven-compiler-plugin helps to resolve imports of the projects, but now maven-compiler doesn't compile the project classes and keep saying "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date".

```
<includes>
    <include>${project.basedir}/WEB-INF/classes</include>
</includes>
```

Comment: A Maven project is configured by the `pom.xml` file, so you need to change the settings there. This is the basic idea of Maven integration: read the `pom.xml` file and automatically configure the project accordingly.

Comment: I am using the pom for the build cycle but Eclipse cannot find imports from external project if I don't add class folder manually though the build is working fine. It is an IDE convenience.